# For loop scrolling through an array. There is an error (this.tiles[i] is undefined). How to fix this?

Tags: javascript

```js
class TileSquare {
  constructor() {
    this.owner = 1;
  }
};

class Group {
  constructor(tiles) {
    this.tiles = tiles;
  }
};


const checkBuild = (group, player) => {
  var ownerSum;

  for (var i = 0; i <= group.tiles.length; i++) {
    if (group.tiles[i].owner === player) {
      ownerSum++;
    }
  }

  return ownerSum;
};

let tile1 = new TileSquare();
let tile2 = new TileSquare();
let group1 = new Group([tile1, tile2]);

console.log(checkBuild(group1, 1));
```

So the checkBuild function is a function that is supposed to check the value of the owner property of different tiles. I'm just beginning my journey with JS and I simply can't figure out why the group.tiles[i] comes out as undefined.

Comment: Try updating this `for (var i = 0; i <= group.tiles[i].owner; i++) {` to this `for (var i = 0; i <= group.tiles.length; i++) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use  `<` rather than `<=`, or else you get an extra iteration

Also, remember to initialize `ownerSum` to `0` so you can increment  it as you want without returning `NaN`

```js
class TileSquare {
  constructor() {
    this.owner = 1;
  }
};

class Group {
  constructor(tiles) {
    this.tiles = tiles;
  }
};


const checkBuild = (group, player) => {
  var ownerSum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < group.tiles.length; i++) {
    if (group.tiles[i].owner === player) {
      ownerSum++;
    }
  }

  return ownerSum;
};

let tile1 = new TileSquare();
let tile2 = new TileSquare();
let group1 = new Group([tile1, tile2]);

console.log(checkBuild(group1, 1));
```

You could also use a [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) here, if you would like

```js
const checkBuild = (group, player) => {
  return group.tiles.reduce((a, {owner}) => owner === player ? a += 1 : a, 0);
};
```

Comment: Okay. So most of these were just typos that I made while reducing the code, but the issue was in fact the "<=" sign instead of "<" sign.